# Allow user to just enter the dollar sign, commas and numbers into an input text field with jquery

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to allow the user to just enter the dollar sign, commas and numbers into an input text field with jquery?

I found similar scripts, but none meets my three needs. Can someone please tell me how can I do this with using just jquery? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the duplicate above and test your specific regex on [regex101](https://regex101.com/#javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pattern` attribute in input element like so

```
<input pattern="(\d|,|\$)+"></input>
```

it accepts a regular expression, which you can tweak to your liking.